# How to set div second color from left bottom corner to right upper corner using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am designing two div blocks for the ID card headers. I can use gradient colors for both but the gradient option is not good for that.

I want to design two blocks like

First-
[image]

As you can see, there are two colors red and blue in the div block.
The blue color from the left bottom corner to the upper corner.

Second -
[image]

There is another div block with white color and red colors. Vertical white color in div block.
I want to design both div like them -
I am creating CSS like that -

```
.main-header
    {
      font-size:23px !important;color:#fff !important; text-shadow: 2px 0 red !important;
font-weight:900 !important; text-align:left;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    border-left:solid blue;
    }
```

How can I get the exact output with the CSS class for the first and second div headers?

Comment: Could you describe why the gradient option doesn’t work and show us what you have tried?

Comment: I was saying,this cannot be done with a gradient. I have attached images and CSS code. I want to like images.

Comment: While I’d probably do the first one with clip path, the second one looks like a relatively simple linear gradient going from left to right to me. Please show us what you have tried so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made your design using `linear-gradient()`. Check and let me know if this works for you.

```css
.block {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.first {
  background: linear-gradient(173deg, red 50%, blue 50%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.second {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 1%, white 2%, red 3%, white 4%, red 5%, white 6%, red 7%, red 94%, white 95%, red 96%, white 97%, red 98%, white 99%, red 100%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="block first">
  Delhi Crime News 24
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="block second">
  Chief Editor
</div>
```